# Use of ` <` in bash script gives (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: bash

I'm getting this error as output

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
something something
something something
```

when i want is

```
something something
something something
```

Below is the bash script. After much trial and error checks i found the error is because of this line

`done < /home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/wired.out;`

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

```
    #!/bin/bash 

    cd /
    cd /home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/

    #INPUT: output file AND number of iterations
    output_file_format="tcp";
    iteration_float=2.0;

    end=5


    iteration=$(printf %.0f $iteration_float);

    r=5

    while [ $r -le $end ]
    do
    ###############################START A ROUND
    l=1;thr=0.0;val=0.0

    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $iteration ]
    do

    while read val
    do
        dir="/home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/"
        #dir=""
        under="_"
        all="all"
        output_file="$dir$output_file_format$under$r$under$r$under$all.out"

        echo -ne "Throughput:          $thr " > $output_file


         if [ $l == '1' ]; then
            thr=$(echo "scale=5; $thr+$val/$iteration_float" | bc )
            echo -ne "throughput: $val " >> $output_file
            fi


        echo "$val"
    done < /home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/wired.out;  #problem because of this

    i=$(($i+1))
    l=0
    #################END AN ITERATION
    done

    r=$(($r+1))
    #######################################END A ROUND
    done
```

Comment: `bash` and `sh` are not the same.  Which do you intend to run this under?  Add a shebang line to specify.

Comment: Running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues it identifies is a good place to start. Beyond that, before ask a question, you need to build a minimal reproducer -- in addition to the MCVE link above, see "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/

Comment: Frankly, the error message you posted looks like one that would come from `bc`, not from `bash`. Using `bash -x yourscript` to run it with tracing would help you identify where the problem is (and thus ask a narrower question).

Comment: As an aside, consider `[ "$l" = 1 ]` -- there's no reason to quote the constant on the right-hand side, but if you don't quote the expansion on the left it can get expanded to multiple words or no words at all. Making sure it's always exactly one word lets `test` give you better error messages (we have *way* too many questions from people who are confused by something that expands to `[ = 1 ]` giving an error about `=` not being a unary operator).

Comment: And `=` is guaranteed to work with all POSIX-compliant versions of `test`, whereas `==` is a nonportable extension; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Similarly, instead of `echo -ne "..."`, consider `printf '%b' "..."` (if you really need the `-e`, or `printf '%s' "..."` if you don't). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: Also, note that in UNIX, a line in a text file is only considered valid if it ends with a newline, so the `-n` is probably not the right thing regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a `bc` error message, not a `bash` error message. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the `done < /home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/wired.out`, except perhaps that if you remove the redirection the loop has no input so its contents don't run at all.

Comment: yes i thought so at first. but i ran the `if` part separately, and it didn't give any errors. If i remove `< /home/afsara/Desktop/ns2_offline/ns_code/wired.out` then the code works fine

Comment: The `<` makes your input come from the file, so something *in the file* is causing bc to fail later. As I suggested earlier, use `set -x` to log what bash is doing, so you can see what arguments it passes to `bc` when you have the `val` read from the file.

Comment: It could be, for example, that your file has DOS newlines in it -- that would lead to `val` values that `bc` doesn't know how to parse.

Comment: i did try but i didn't understand what `++` meant at the beginning and then kept looking for what it meant and ignored the rest :|

Comment: Ahh. (For the record, the sigils at the front indicate nesting depth, so the number you have tells how many functions/etc. the current scope is inside of).